# With what granularity can I access the main memory using pointers?

Tags: pointers, memory

If I were to assign a pointer "p1" to a generic address, incremented that address by the smallest possible amount, and assigned that incremented address to pointer "p2", how many bits of memory would there be between the addresses of the two pointers? Is the answer CPU-specific? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What language are you programming with? Do you have to tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addresses in any computer are byte addresses. It is not possible to have a smaller granularity when considering memory access.

You can completely access successive bytes in memory by incrementing a pointer, but you must have a pointer to bytes (for instance char or unsigned char in C).

If your pointer points to another kind of entity (ints, floats, structs, etc), incrementing the pointer will lead you to the next entity. For instance, with a p is pointer to an int (4 bytes), p++ will add to p size of an int (4).

Google "pointer arithmetic" if not familiar with these concepts.